# Installing Ubuntu running on Virtualbox as operating system on computer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have an Ubuntu 18 running on my Virtualbox, I have updated the system, installed a lot of programs (python, numpy, pandas, tensorflow etc.) and added several plugins.
Is there any way to install this exact image of Ubuntu as an operating system on my  computer without the need to install all these programs again?

Comment: probably but probably quiet complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately you want to convert your vmdk file into an iso file, so that you could use it outside of a virtual environment. Convert the vmdk to a raw file with qemu:

```
qemu-img convert -f vmdk filename.vmdk -O raw filename.raw
```

Mount the raw file as a loopback device:

```
mkdir raw_mount
mount -o loop filename.raw raw_mount
```

And then generate an ISO from its contents:

```
mkisofs -o filename.iso raw_mount/
```

[This blog post](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/convert-vm-iso) has more detailed instructions if you get stuck.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, not a good idea because the hardware environment as seen by the OS isn't the same (a VBox is a rather "simplified" hardware) and you could end up with a system with limited functionality (for instance there is no Wifi in the VBox, and yourgraphics cards would not have the proper driver installed).

You can list the installed packages in your VBox:

```
sudo dpkg-query -f '${binary:Package}\n' -W > packages_list.txt
```

And the use that list in a fresh system to install the packages (many will be already installed):

```
sudo xargs -a packages_list.txt apt install
```

You can even restrict the list above to the packages you explicitly installed, see several methods [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2389/generating-list-of-manually-installed-packages-and-querying-individual-packages#492343).

Of course this doesn't take in account things you have installed outside the package manager (python packages installed via PIP for instance), but there are likely similar procedures (using `pip list` for instance).